# How to write this in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

This is what I could come up with. And it was wrong!

```
<%= text_field_tag('datetimepicker',
    content_tag(:span, 
        content_tag(:i,
            {data-time-icon:'icon-time'},
            {data-date-icon:'icon-calendar'}
        ),
        {class: 'add-on'}
    ),
    {class: 'input-append'}
)%>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You text field doesn't have any id, name or anything inside it, so it should look just like what it is now. If you want an answer in haml, then go to http://htmltohaml.com

Comment: Why are you writing it with tag helpers? What is wrong with normal HTML in this case?

Comment: Looks like text_field_tag couldn't pick up more arguments. I agree with you @LoganSerman. Actually this goes inside a form. I want to input the date into start date and time. I tried this: <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
                 <%= u.text_field :sdatetime, id:'datetimepicker2' %>   
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
It turned out okay! :D \m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**text_field_tag** is for **input**, for other you can use content_tag

This is your current markup:

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Using Rails helpers it can be modified to :

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class=> "input-append date", :id => 'datetimepicker' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag '' %>
  <%= content_tag :span, :class => "add-on" do %>
    <%= content_tag :i, :data => {:time-icon => 'icon-time', :date-icon => 'icon-calendar'} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However I prefer Basic HTML over these ActionView Helpers, unless its helping out with code, which in this case is not much..

Comment: Have not used or tried 'do end' before. Informative. Thanks.